# Setting Cookies

Tags: cookies

I'm created two themes *(light & dark)* but I'm not sure how to set cookies so the theme will remain constant when the user navigates from page-to-page or comes back to the site next week. Is there a simple script I can add to my existing code?

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
  <link id="lightTheme" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleSheetLightTheme.css">
  <link id="darkTheme" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleSheetDarkTheme.css">
<script>
  function darkTheme() {
    var theme = document.getElementById('lightTheme');
    theme.href = "styleSheetDarkTheme.css";
  }

  function lightTheme() {
    var theme = document.getElementById('lightTheme');
    theme.href = "styleSheetLightTheme.css";
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="#" onClick="darkTheme(); return false;">Dark Theme</a>
|
<a href="#" onClick="lightTheme(); return false;">Light Theme</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**styleSheetDarkTheme.css**

```
body {background-color: #333; font-family: verdana; color: #ccc;}
a:link, a:visited, a:active {color: #fff; text-decoration: none;}
a:hover {color: #0ff;}
```

**styleSheetLightTheme.css**

```
body {background-color: #eee; font-family: verdana; color: #333;}
a:link, a:visited, a:active {color: #000; text-decoration: none;}
a:hover {color: #0ff;}
```

Comment: This framework is pretty handy for managing cookies: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie also, I hope you plan to conditionally load the styles depending on which theme is in use, rather than always loading them both :) saving bandwidth is always a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution with cookie**  [wordpress]

You will need [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).
Create javascript file "themechanger.js":

```
(function($){

    var theme = $.cookie("styles");
    var themehref = document.getElementById(theme_styles.rel_id);

    setTheme = function(mode){
        if (theme == mode)
            return;
        if (mode == 'light') {
            $.cookie('styles', mode);
            themehref.href = theme_styles.light;
        }
        else if (mode == 'dark') {
            $.cookie('styles', mode);
            themehref.href = theme_styles.dark;
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

In `functions.php` enqueue styles and javascript:

```
add_action('init', 'load_styles', 15);
function load_styles() {

    $current_style = '/styleSheetLightTheme.css';
    if ( isset($_COOKIE['styles']) && $_COOKIE['styles'] == "dark")
        $current_style = '/styleSheetDarkTheme.css';
    wp_register_style( 'stylename', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . $current_style );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'stylename');

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery_cookie', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js.cookie.js', ['jquery'] );
    wp_register_script( 'theme_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/themechanger.js', ['jquery', 'jquery_cookie'] );
    //
    // object "theme_styles" will store links to style, used in javascript
    wp_localize_script( 'theme_script', 'theme_styles', [
        'light' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/styleSheetLightTheme.css',
        'dark' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/styleSheetDarkTheme.css',
        'rel_id' => 'stylename-css',
    ]);
    wp_enqueue_script('theme_script');
}
```

To change theme style use javascript function `setTheme()`

```
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="setTheme('dark'); return false;">Dark Theme</a><br>
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="setTheme('light'); return false;">Light Theme</a>
```

---

**Local storage** [for your code]:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link id="my_style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleSheetLightTheme.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var theme = localStorage.getItem('styles');
        var themehref = document.getElementById('my_style');
        var base_url = 'styleSheet{{mode}}.css';

        // default value
        if(!theme)
            localStorage.setItem('styles','light');

        if (theme == 'dark')
            themehref.href = base_url.replace('{{mode}}', 'DarkTheme');
        else
            themehref.href = base_url.replace('{{mode}}', "LightTheme");

        function setTheme(mode){
            if ( (mode != 'light' && mode != 'dark'))
                return;

            theme = localStorage.getItem('styles');
            // don't change if it's already active
            if (mode == theme)
                return;
            if (mode == 'light') {
                localStorage.setItem('styles', 'light');
                themehref.href = base_url.replace('{{mode}}', 'LightTheme');
            }
            else if (mode == 'dark') {
                localStorage.setItem('styles', 'dark');
                themehref.href = base_url.replace('{{mode}}', 'DarkTheme');
            }
        }
    </script>

    <a href="javascript:;" onClick="setTheme('dark'); return false;">Dark Theme</a>
    |
    <a href="javascript:;" onClick="setTheme('light'); return false;">Light Theme</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Local Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). It is really simple to use and also pure JavaScript. Supported by all modern browsers ([according to caniuse website](https://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage)).

You can use this code;

```
<script>
var theme_var = localStorage.getItem('styles');
var themehref = document.getElementById('lightTheme');

if(!theme_var) {
    localStorage.setItem('styles','lightTheme');
    themehref.href = "styleSheet"+localStorage.getItem('styles')+".css";
} else {
    themehref.href = "styleSheet"+theme_var+".css";
}

function setThemeItem(themevar){
    themehref.href = "styleSheet"+theme_var+".css";
    localStorage.setItem('styles',themevar);
}
</script>

//Usage
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="setThemeItem('darkTheme'); return false;">Dark Theme</a>
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="setThemeItem('lightTheme'); return false;">Light Theme</a>
```